# How to prevent comment posting when it has specific words in it?

Tags: comments, advertising

I´ve searched for all Drupal 7 modules that try to give some SPAM protection, but haven´t found what I need, maybe I´ve overlooked something?

I need to **prevent anonymous comment posting when comment has specific -configurable- spammy words**. How may I do that?

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56392/how-to-stop-spam-in-comments

Comment: Thanks! HoneyPot (http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) did the trick! I didn´t want to use Mollom because I don´t want to use third party stuff whenever I can.
It´s not exactly what I wanted, but it does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Spam](https://drupal.org/node/498092) module.

It runs filters on posted content, for example using regexps.

Another way is to write a Rule that examines posted comments and deny them if certain words are found, but unfortunately this module is only available for Drupal 6.

And also you can write a validate function to the comment form, examine the content on submission and use form_set_error if you detect those words. To do this just implemente the hook_form_alter (or the hook form alter with form id), add your valditation function:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'you_custom_validate_function';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I haven´t thought on using Rules! 
Sadly, Spam module is D6 only.

Comment: Oops, I didn't check the Spam module availability. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Mollom](https://drupal.org/project/mollom) built by the same gentleman who created Drupal.

> Mollom is an "intelligent" content moderation web service. By
>   monitoring content activity on all sites in the Mollom network, Mollom
>   is in a unique position to determine if a post is potentially spam;
>   not only based on the posted content, but also on the past activity
>   and reputation of the poster. In short, Mollom handles incoming posts
>   intelligently, in much the same way a human moderator decides what
>   posts are acceptable. Therefore, Mollom enables you to allow anonymous
>   users to post comments and other content on your site.

Comment: Mollom does not have a configurable list of spammy words.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [word filter](https://drupal.org/project/wordfilter) module

> For example, you can set the filter to find the word "work" and when found, change it to "play". You may toggle whether the filter applies to node titles as well as the body

It also has filtering for comments.